# Server-side load balancing and Third-Party discovery with Zuul & Consul / Eureka

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, service-discovery

we are planning to built our next projects using microservices-architecture and we have already defined that we want to use Zuul as API-Gateway. Right now we have to decide which service registry we will use:

Consul or Eureka.

We want to use server-side load balancing (via Zuul itself). Is it possible to do this while combining Zuul with Consul or Eureka?

Furthermore, we don’t want to use self-registration pattern! Our plan is to use Third-Party registration! Is it possible while combining Zuul with Consul or Eureka? Which tools can be used for this? Are there alternatives for Registrator which works for Docker?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!